# How to find jobs for someone who holds a PhD degree but lacks English proficiency?

Tags: phd, career-path, job

Does anybody know how to find jobs for someone who holds a PhD degree but lacks English proficiency?

My mother, who was a professor at a reputable university back in my home country, came to the United States for my education and since then, she has been working as a babysitter and at dry cleaners, and I'm increasingly noticing her misery. She is fluent in Korean and Chinese (native bilingual proficiency), but her English, especially in terms of writing, is on an elementary level. Looking for jobs online that fit her specific situation proved to be extremely difficult. I'm trying to reach out to my professional network, which is pretty small to begin with. That leaves me thinking whether I should look up specific bilingual companies on LinkedIn. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What is her field?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about finding jobs outside academia.

Comment: I know samsung prefers people that speak korean, for instance, but english would be nevertheless essential in the US. IMHO, step 0: improve the english proficiency...

Comment: @DavidRicherby Personally I think it is on topic. It is a question about a situation that concerns university professors specifically.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Non-academic jobs for recent PhD graduates is off-topic, even though it concerns PhD students specifically. How is this question different?

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you want a hard rule written in stone on what is on topic and what is not, I don't have it (and I don't think there is / should be one). But to me this feels like it should be on topic because it is a much more specific case. The PhD -> industry transition is a "standard path" covered by many more sources (and by workplace.se, presumably). This one is a very special situation involving a university professor, that they are in *because* they are university professors.

Comment: I vote to "Leave Closed" because this question is unclear to me. The OP has not responded to @FedericoPoloni's inquiry "What is her field?". Once the OP clarifies this, I am more than happy to vote to re-open. Thanks.